# Repeatedly running a data step if URL fails to load

Tags: sas

I am creating a dataset using filename URL web submissions. However, in some instaces I keep getting '502' responses from the server. To get around this I would like to use some conditional logic inside a macro. I'm most of the way there, but I cant quite get the end bit to work. The idea is that the macro, which is nested within other nested macros will keep trying this one submission until it gets a dataset that doesn't have 0 observations then move on:

```
%macro test_exst;

filename loader url "http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=&svar1.+&svar2.+&svar3.+&svar4.+&svar5.+&svar6.+&svar7.+&svar8.+&svar9.+&svar10.+
&svar11.+&svar12.+&svar13.+&svar14.+&svar15.+&svar16.+&svar17.+&svar18.+&svar19.+&svar20.+
&svar21.+&svar22.+&svar23.+&svar24.+&svar25.+&svar26.+&svar27.+&svar28.+&svar29.+&svar30.+
&svar31.+&svar32.+&svar33.+&svar34.+&svar35.+&svar36.+&svar37.+&svar38.+&svar39.+&svar40.+
&svar41.+&svar42.+&svar43.+&svar44.+&svar45.+&svar46.+&svar47.+&svar48.+&svar49.+&svar50.+
&svar51.+&svar52.+&svar53.+&svar54.+&svar55.+&svar56.+&svar57.+&svar58.+&svar59.+&svar60.+
&svar61.+&svar62.+&svar63.+&svar64.+&svar65.+&svar66.+&svar67.+&svar68.+&svar69.+&svar70.+
&svar71.+&svar72.+&svar73.+&svar74.+&svar75.+&svar76.+&svar77.+&svar78.+&svar79.+&svar80.+
&svar81.+&svar82.+&svar83.+&svar84.+&svar85.+&svar86.+&svar87.+&svar88.+&svar89.+&svar90.+
&svar91.+&svar92.+&svar93.+&svar94.+&svar95.+&svar96.+&svar97.+&svar98.+&svar99.+&svar100.+
&svar101.+&svar102.+&svar103.+&svar104.+&svar105.+&svar106.+&svar107.+&svar108.+&svar109.+&svar110.+
&svar111.+&svar112.+&svar113.+&svar114.+&svar115.+&svar116.+&svar117.+&svar118.+&svar119.+&svar120.+
&svar121.+&svar122.+&svar123.+&svar124.+&svar125.+&svar126.+&svar127.+&svar128.+&svar129.+&svar130.+
&svar131.+&svar132.+&svar133.+&svar134.+&svar135.+&svar136.+&svar137.+&svar138.+&svar139.+&svar140.+
&svar141.+&svar142.+&svar143.+&svar144.+&svar145.+&svar146.+&svar147.+&svar148.+&svar149.+&svar150.+
&svar151.+&svar152.+&svar153.+&svar154.+&svar155.+&svar156.+&svar157.+&svar158.+&svar159.+&svar160.+
&svar161.+&svar162.+&svar163.+&svar164.+&svar165.+&svar166.+&svar167.+&svar168.+&svar169.+&svar170.+
&svar171.+&svar172.+&svar173.+&svar174.+&svar175.+&svar176.+&svar177.+&svar178.+&svar179.+&svar180.+
&svar181.+&svar182.+&svar183.+&svar184.+&svar185.+&svar186.+&svar187.+&svar188.+&svar189.+&svar190.+
&svar191.+&svar192.+&svar193.+&svar194.+&svar195.+&svar196.+&svar197.+&svar198.+&svar199.+&svar200.
&f=&&fvar&a." DEBUG ;


/*  data step based on filename url above goes here, each pass will give 500 metrics x 1 symbol dataset*/

%put create dataset from csv submission;

data temp_&I._&&fvar&a.;
   infile loader length=len MISSOVER /*delimiter = ','*/;
/*   input record $varying8192. len; */
   input record $varying30. len; 
   format record $30.;
   informat record $30.;      
run;

data _null_;
   dsid=open("temp_&I._&&fvar&a.");
   obs=attrn(dsid,"nobs");
   put "number of observations = " obs;
   if obs = 0 then stop;
   else;


filename loader url "http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=&svar1.+&svar2.+&svar3.+&svar4.+&svar5.+&svar6.+&svar7.+&svar8.+&svar9.+&svar10.+
&svar11.+&svar12.+&svar13.+&svar14.+&svar15.+&svar16.+&svar17.+&svar18.+&svar19.+&svar20.+
&svar21.+&svar22.+&svar23.+&svar24.+&svar25.+&svar26.+&svar27.+&svar28.+&svar29.+&svar30.+
&svar31.+&svar32.+&svar33.+&svar34.+&svar35.+&svar36.+&svar37.+&svar38.+&svar39.+&svar40.+
&svar41.+&svar42.+&svar43.+&svar44.+&svar45.+&svar46.+&svar47.+&svar48.+&svar49.+&svar50.+
&svar51.+&svar52.+&svar53.+&svar54.+&svar55.+&svar56.+&svar57.+&svar58.+&svar59.+&svar60.+
&svar61.+&svar62.+&svar63.+&svar64.+&svar65.+&svar66.+&svar67.+&svar68.+&svar69.+&svar70.+
&svar71.+&svar72.+&svar73.+&svar74.+&svar75.+&svar76.+&svar77.+&svar78.+&svar79.+&svar80.+
&svar81.+&svar82.+&svar83.+&svar84.+&svar85.+&svar86.+&svar87.+&svar88.+&svar89.+&svar90.+
&svar91.+&svar92.+&svar93.+&svar94.+&svar95.+&svar96.+&svar97.+&svar98.+&svar99.+&svar100.+
&svar101.+&svar102.+&svar103.+&svar104.+&svar105.+&svar106.+&svar107.+&svar108.+&svar109.+&svar110.+
&svar111.+&svar112.+&svar113.+&svar114.+&svar115.+&svar116.+&svar117.+&svar118.+&svar119.+&svar120.+
&svar121.+&svar122.+&svar123.+&svar124.+&svar125.+&svar126.+&svar127.+&svar128.+&svar129.+&svar130.+
&svar131.+&svar132.+&svar133.+&svar134.+&svar135.+&svar136.+&svar137.+&svar138.+&svar139.+&svar140.+
&svar141.+&svar142.+&svar143.+&svar144.+&svar145.+&svar146.+&svar147.+&svar148.+&svar149.+&svar150.+
&svar151.+&svar152.+&svar153.+&svar154.+&svar155.+&svar156.+&svar157.+&svar158.+&svar159.+&svar160.+
&svar161.+&svar162.+&svar163.+&svar164.+&svar165.+&svar166.+&svar167.+&svar168.+&svar169.+&svar170.+
&svar171.+&svar172.+&svar173.+&svar174.+&svar175.+&svar176.+&svar177.+&svar178.+&svar179.+&svar180.+
&svar181.+&svar182.+&svar183.+&svar184.+&svar185.+&svar186.+&svar187.+&svar188.+&svar189.+&svar190.+
&svar191.+&svar192.+&svar193.+&svar194.+&svar195.+&svar196.+&svar197.+&svar198.+&svar199.+&svar200.
&f=&&fvar&a." DEBUG ;

data temp_&I._&&fvar&a.;
       infile loader length=len MISSOVER /*delimiter = ','*/;
    /*   input record $varying8192. len; */
       input record $varying30. len; 
       format record $30.;
       informat record $30.;      
    run;


    run;

    %mend;

    %test_exst;
```

The idea here is try URL submission, create dataset from it, check number of obs is not zero. If its not end the macro. If it is resubmit the same filename URL then create the dataset from it again. Keep doing this until the server respond, the exit the macro and most on to the rest of the code.

I haven't got as far as running this code in anger yet. I'm guessing the filename URL will work fine, but it is the fact that the code is attempting to create a dataset within a data *null* step right at the end that is making it fall over. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: You're not actually doing anything in that `data _null_` data step.  You're opening a dataset, you're seeing if it has any records, and putting those number of recrods.  The stop is irrelevant - the else; also would cancel it.  Then you start another data step, which ends the `data _null_` step.

Comment: Ive amended the logic to:

if obs <> 0 then do;
end;
if obs = 0 then do;
<resubmit filename URL step>;
end;

Now it says there is an unclosed do loop and doesn't execute the filename URL. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not understanding how SAS works, probably, at a more fundamental level than I can really explain here.  Among other things, the `filename` statement is NOT conditionally executable - it doesn't even belong inside a datastep.  The `input` is really what is conditionally executable, none of the rest of it.

Comment: Can you suggest an alternative way of coding it?

Comment: I don't think it's clear enough what exactly you're doing to do so, or I probably would have.  In general, it sounds like you might want to write a recursive macro; so, write the data step once in the macro (ie, write it as if it worked properly every time), then do a check of the count (which you can do in the very same data step, with `call symputx("obscount",_n_)` - if that value is 1, it didn't read any data in), and if that value indicates it did not work, recursively call the same macro.  Just keep a counter to make sure you don't get in an infinite loop, ie, try 10 times or something.

Comment: OK, I put that as an answer, and (I think) improved your title.  Your `data _null_` bit was really irrelevant; I think this title reflects what you are trying to do, if not then please improve it further.

Comment: Can you reduce the code in this question to a more minimal set? It's hurting my eyes to read everything. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Without getting into the specifics of your project, a good way to approach this generally is with recursion.

```
%macro test_me(iter);
 %let iter=%eval(&iter.+1);
 data my_data;
   infile myfilename;
   input stuff;
   call symputx("obscount",_n_);
 run;

 %if &obscount=1 and &iter. < 10 %then %do;
   %put Iteration &iter. failed, trying again;
   %test_me(&iter.);
 %end;
%mend test_me;

%test_me(0);
```

It checks to see if it worked, and if it did not work, it calls itself again, with a maximum iteration count to make sure you don't end up in infinite loop land if the server is down or somesuch.  You also might put a delay in there if the server has a maximum frequency of calls or any other rules the API requires you to follow.

Comment: %macro test_exst(iter);

filename loader url "my URL" DEBUG ;


/* data step based on filename url above goes here, each pass will give 500 metrics x 1 symbol dataset*/

%put create dataset from csv submission;

 %let &iter=&iter.+1;

 data temp_&I._&&fvar&a.;
   infile loader length=len MISSOVER /*delimiter = ','*/;
   input record $varying30. len; 
   format record $30.;
   informat record $30.;   
   call symputx("obscount",_n_);
 run;

 %if &obscount=1 and &iter. < 10 %then %do;
   %put Iteration &iter. failed, trying again;
   %test_exst(&iter.);
 %end;
%mend test_exst;

%test_exst(0);

Comment: I got the following error:

That is the exact code I have used and got the following error:

ERROR: Expecting a variable name after %LET.
ERROR: Symbolic variable name 0 must begin with a letter or underscore.
ERROR: The macro TEST_EXST will stop executing.

Comment: Oh, the let should be `%let iter=iter+1`.

Comment: Joe, shouldn't it be `%LET ITER = %EVAL(&ITER + 1)` ?

Comment: Yeah, that's probably better. Probably shouldn't post half an hour before quitting time :)

Comment: The code is running ok. Just kicked it off now but have yet to encounter any 502 returns to confirm the logic loop.

Comment: When a 502 return code was received the following error was thrown up by the logic:

ERROR: A character operand was found in the %EVAL function or %IF condition where a numeric operand
       is required. The condition was: &obscount=1 and &iter. < 10
ERROR: The macro TEST_EXST will stop executing.

Comment: You might want to pre-load obscount with a 1 - if you have _no_ observations in the dataset it might not even hit _n_ = 1.

Comment: I think that:

%if &obscount=1 and %eval(&iter.) < 10 %then %do;

has fixed the issue, but im still observing the log at the minute. if i get a 502 response the dataset will almost always return zero obs so i will look at that additional piece of logic.

Comment: putting an %eval line into the above problem line of code didnt work. any suggestions?